# Delete mail message like Gmail using jQuery

Tags: jquery, gmail

When using Gmail I notice that at INBOX page it displays 1-50 by default. When I delete a msg, then it automatically fetch the 51'th item to display at inbox page. I know that If I delete a row then it lost using jQuery/Ajax but it display the next item very quickly within no time.

How is it possible?? Any standard method??

Thanks,
Rashidul

Answer (score 1):

When you delete some rows, save a reference to how many were deleted and request the next n set of items and load them into the DOM.

Comment: Then how many I need to load at first. ALL? willn't it cause a slower loading [more loading time].

Comment: @rashed Whatever number you want at first.